# Is there a way to hide the formula in a Google sheet cell?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I want to block certain users/groups from viewing formulas in certain cells in Google sheet, but they'll have permission to edit other cells values. All they will be able to see is the result.
explanation: it's an advanced calculator. let's say that I want to give the user the ability to put values in cells `A1` and `B1`, and in `C1` the formula is `=A1+B1`.
I want to hide the formula in C1, so the user will only the the result.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, how about using web publish of the Spreadsheet as one of several methods? In this case, users can see only the values. But I couldn't understand about your detail situation from your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: if you don't want the formula viewing by some user, you can add interface protected sheet, put the formula here with data from your current sheet, and then you do importrange the result to your current sheet

Comment: As a workaround: You can hide column C (disabling permissions to show it) and implement e.g. in D1  `=C1` like this the user might see the formula `=C1`, but this will not give away any critical information

Comment: In google sheet no method to hide formula like excel, so we must make a trick to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to do it depending on how/who is working on the sheet. If people aren't familiar with sheets you can actually hide the formula in a row at the top by using array formulas so in the header:

```
={" header title" ; arrayformula(a2:a+b2:b)}
```

The formula would be hidden in the cell that shows the header, all the cells below would just be the calculation. If you hide the row that has the arrayformula and protect it no one will be able to see it. The only thing is you have to also protect the column otherwise if someone hardcodes a value in the column the formula will stop working.

The second option (easier but can run into more issues is the have a 'mirror' copy of the sheet they are interacting with in the same file as a hidden sheet. Basically a duplicate of the tab with all the cells a direct reference of the first tab. So:

Sheet1 = tab they interact with

Sheet2 = 'mirror' tab with every cell being ='Sheet1'!a1, but for the corresponding cell value.

As they edit Sheet the values entered in Sheet1 will show up in Sheet2, then the calculations can happen on that sheet, and then Sheet1, can just be a direct reference to that column in Sheet2. So the calculations in Sheet1 will only appear ='Sheet2'!C2. If you protect Sheet2 and hide it no one will be able to see the formulas. Sheet1 could even reference Sheet2 with an index formula like: index(column sheet2,,) which would return the entire column from sheet2.

Comment: The second option (mirror sheet) works for me, with hiding the first sheet and disable download of the sheet for viewers and editors. Thanks